# Search and Replace Linux

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I am trying to do the following search and replace, but for some reason it's not working.  I am trying to replace:

`require_once('`

with

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/'`

Those are the **exact** srings (slash and single quote included).

This is what I attempted, however I can't get it to work:

```
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/require_once(\'/require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . \'\//g" {} \;
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Do you get an error message? I think the problem is with the escaping of special characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` and `/` characters:

```
sed "s/require_once('/require_once(\$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']\/'/g"
```

Comment: One can use `@` as delimiter for sed, so you do not need to escape `/`. e.g.: sed -e 's@/asd/@b@'. But you will still need to escape `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to backslash-escape the dollar sign within double quotes, otherwise the shell interpolates the (nonexistent) environment variable `_SERVER`, replacing it with an empty string.